# convert 'mm-dd-yyyy' string date into 'yyyy-mm-dd' javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime-format, date-formatting

I am getting dates from an API in one of these formats `"mm-dd-yyyy"` or `"mm/dd/yyyy"` also these are in string and I want to parse them from string to js date object

so when I do `new Date('12/07/2021')` or `new Date('12-07-2021')` I get the output date which has one day previous `2021-12-06T18:30:00:000Z`.

But if I pass the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format like this `new Date('2021-12-07')` then I get correct date as output `2021-12-07T00:00:00.000Z`  I am facing this issue in the backend with node js.

possible solution according to me is converting the string from `mm-dd-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` format. But how do I do this ?

**NOTE:** : I cant use moment js as this is a new project and due to moment js depreciation

Comment: Erm. Curious. What's your local timezone?

Comment: _"due to moment js depreciation"_ - momentjs is not deprecated yet. They also mention multiple alternatives on their site...

Answer (score 0):

There are UTC variants of setDay, setMonth, setYear that should do what your after.

eg..

```js
function mdyToDate(date) {
  const s = date.split(/[/-]/);
  const [m, d, y] = s.map(v => parseInt(v));
  const ret = new Date('2000-01-01');
  ret.setUTCFullYear(y);
  ret.setUTCMonth(m-1); //months are 0 based
  ret.setUTCDate(d);
  return ret;
}

console.log(mdyToDate('12/07/2021'));
console.log(mdyToDate('12-07-2021'));
console.log(mdyToDate('12/7-2021'));
```